# Text Not going to php file when uploading text and image to server from iOS

Tags: php, ios

I am attempting to send an image and UITextField.text data to a server.  I am able to get the image over but the text data never gets there it seems.  Basically I am going to rename the image on the PHP side.

XCode

```
- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 0);
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.mywebsite.net/app/upload.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imagename\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[textField.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(returnString);
```

}

PHP

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './'; //Uploading to same directory as PHP file
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$imageName = basename($_POST['imagename']['name']);
$uploadFile = $file;

// $randomNumber = rand(0, 99999);

$newName = $uploadDir . $imageName . $uploadFile;

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
    echo $file;
} else {
    echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
}

if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 300000000000) {
    exit("Your file is too large.");
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
    $postsize = ini_get('post_max_size'); //Not necessary, I was using these
    $canupload = ini_get('file_uploads'); //server variables to see what was
    $tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir'); //going wrong.
    $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    echo "http://www.iroboticshowoff.com/dir/{$file}" . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
} ?>
```

I'd really like to use AFNetworking but I can't find any good tutorials using the newest version.  Looks like AFJSON... was removed and everything I've seen is calling for it.

As I said image uploads fine, now I'm looking to get the textField data over there.

Comment: you're just assuming the upload works. There's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason.

Comment: I can confirm the image does upload.  After I saveData, I check the server and the image is there.

Comment: well, your text is probably just `$_POST['imagename']`, not `$_POST['imagename']['name']`. doing `var_dump($_POST)` would show what you REALLY received. if your name isn't there, then your ios code isn't sending it properly.

Comment: That was it.  Kinda feel stupid when the solution was right there the whole time.  Thanks so much Marc B!